# Из-за чего не сработало событие onclick?

Tags: jquery, javascript

**Файл html:**

```
onclick = "return Editor.edit(this, 'article');"
```

**Файл js:**

```
Editor = {

        init: function (cb){
            var title = '.namePost';
            var text  = '.text';
        },

        edit: function (this, type){
            alert('dd');
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**Ошибка:**

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Editor is not
> defined

Comment: Ваш js обернут в window.onload или ему подобное?

Comment: Нет, тогда можно js обернуть в ready()?
_____

Что лучше, кстати, использовать?

Comment: Можно. И не используйте установку события в html, это плохой подход.
Почему бы не сделать так?

$(element).on('click', Editor.edit);

Comment: Я когда обернул код в `window.onload = function() {};` - не могу получить доступ к переменной так: $(document).on("keyup", Editor.title_edit, `function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13){  
        alert('dd');
     return false;
    }
});`

Comment: В методе on второй параметр - селектор.

Comment: Разве я не могу передать имя селектора?

Comment: Тогда я не понимаю вашей проблемы.

Comment: Вот [здесь][1]есть ответ по поводу Enter.


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/362041/javascript-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4